# Error Message "The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side" in Matlab for Neural Net

Tags: matlab, neural-network, error-messaging

Hello I want to Estimate Two PetroPhysical Properties in Oil Reservoir Rock Using Well Logging Values and I have some Neural Network Codes in Matlab 
(R2014b Version) in MLP Method.

This is Important to say I used Interesting Technique for Determining Optimum Neuron Number in Single Hidden Layer: in First assigned Neuron Number to 5 and this Neuron Number Growed to 100 Number based on Step Length equal to 5, i.e : 5,10,15,...,100

Now For Determining Optimum Neuron Number, I Wrote A code for plot a Graph that There is Neuron Number in X-Axis and Error Value (Last Iteration in 
Training Stage) in Y-Axis , That I Wrote This Code Below:

```
nnn1=5;                             % First Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer
nnnj=5;                             % Jump in Number of Neurons 
nnnf=100;                           % Last Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer


% Training Network

it=25;                                             % Max Number of   Iteration
ii=0;
netopt{:}=1:nnnf;
for nnn=nnn1:nnnj:nnnf
ii=ii+1; nnn
net1=newff(p,t,[nnn nnn],{'purelin','purelin'},'traingd'); 

evalopt(ii)=10^5;

for i=1:it
    [net1,tr,y,et]=train(net1,p,t);             % Training
    net1.divideParam.trainRatio=trainRatio1;
    net1.divideParam.valRatio=valRatio1;
    net1.divideParam.testRatio=testRatio1;
    estval=sim(net1,p(:,tr.valInd)); 
    eval=mse(estval-t(:,tr.valInd));
    if  eval<evalopt(ii)
        netopt{(ii)}=net1; tropt(ii)=tr; evalopt(ii)=eval;
    end
end
end

plot(nnn1:nnnj:nnnf,evalopt)
```

but When I Push "Run Section" Button in Last Line Of Above Codes, Matlab Shows This Error Message : "The right hand side of this assignment has too 
few values to satisfy the left hand side"   Instead of Plotting Above Mentioned Graph. Please Guide Me for Fix This Error in Matlab...
I wrote All my Codes in Below Again...

```
clc; clear; close all
data=xlsread('sarvak_normalized.xlsx');  % Input File
corrplot(data)

input=[1:9]; % Input Layer
p=data(:,input);
output=[10:11];                        % Output Layer
t=data(:,output);
p=p'; t=t';                         % Transposing Matrices



trainRatio1=.6;
valRatio1=.2;
testRatio1=.2;


%% Network Definition

nnn1=5;                             % First Number of Neurons in Hidden  Layer
nnnj=5;                             % Jump in Number of Neurons 
nnnf=100;                           % Last Number of Neurons in Hidden Layer



% Training Network

it=25;                                             % Max Number of Iteration
ii=0;
netopt{:}=1:nnnf;
for nnn=nnn1:nnnj:nnnf
ii=ii+1; nnn
net1=newff(p,t,[nnn nnn],{'purelin','purelin'},'traingd'); 

evalopt(ii)=10^5;

for i=1:it
    [net1,tr,y,et]=train(net1,p,t);             % Training
    net1.divideParam.trainRatio=trainRatio1;
    net1.divideParam.valRatio=valRatio1;
    net1.divideParam.testRatio=testRatio1;
    estval=sim(net1,p(:,tr.valInd)); 
    eval=mse(estval-t(:,tr.valInd));
    if  eval<evalopt(ii)
        netopt{(ii)}=net1; tropt(ii)=tr; evalopt(ii)=eval;
    end
end
end

plot(nnn1:nnnj:nnnf,evalopt)


nn=2

ptrain=p(:,tropt(nn).trainInd);     ttrain=t(:,tropt(nn).trainInd);      esttrain=sim(netopt{nn},ptrain);
ptest=p(:,tropt(nn).testInd);       ttest=t(:,tropt(nn).testInd);        esttest=sim(netopt{nn},ptest);
pval=p(:,tropt(nn).valInd);         tval=t(:,tropt(nn).valInd);          estval=sim(netopt{nn},pval);
estwhole=sim(netopt{nn},p);



plotregression(ttrain,esttrain,'Train',tval,estval,'Validation',...
ttest,esttest,'Test',t,estwhole,'Whole Data');
```

Also Same Error Message Occurs When I Push "Run Section" Button in Last Line Of Full Codes ; " plotregression ..." For Understand Model Accuracy in 3 
Stages of Neural Net Process.

OfCourse Sometimes Matlab Plots Regression Graphs but Shows Error Message for " plot(nnn1:nnnj:nnnf,evalopt) " and conversely  and Sometimes dont Plot any Graph. Thank you...

Comment: Is this a minimal example to reproduce your problem? see [mcve].

Comment: Yes, Exactly; I Wrote my Neural Net Full Codes for reproduce my problem.

Comment: Full Codes Are necessary For Proper Run Of This Program.